# WordPress Database

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a user defined table in wordpress database. Is it possible?.........how?

Comment: What do you mean by "user defined table"? What is the purpose of this table?

Comment: DotNetNuke has a core module named UserDefinedTable (renamed to Form and List) and it allows users to define data fields from a predefined list of data types. Do you mean this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create your custome table, but make sure that you are able to manipulate/use it in wordpress CMS.